# Azure easy tables contains data, but API returns empty array

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have multiple easy tables that contain data.

[image: Provinces easy table]
[image: definitions]

However, when I try to access this data with the API endpoint (https://--url--.azurewebsites.net/tables/Provinces?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0), it returns

```
[]
```

Any idea? I did not modify the backend code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I checked the option "Soft delete" when I created the database. All tables need "deleted" property as boolean to properly operate.